# Set lc_monetary for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, collation, postgresql-10

How do I set `lc_monetary` to show `money` ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html)) data type as EUR?

I tried:

- change `postgresql.conf` and set `lc_monetary="de_DE.UTF-8@euro`. PG will not start with this change (currently set to `en_US.UTF-8`)
- do the same through pgAdmin and psql (using `set`) and I get `ERROR: invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary"`

My current collation is `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Locales depend on the operating system. Check what locales are available

```
select * 
from pg_collation
where collname ~ any(array['DE', 'FR', 'GR', 'IE'])

  collname  | collnamespace | collowner | collencoding | collcollate | collctype  
------------+---------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+------------
 en_IE      |            11 |        10 |            6 | en_IE.utf8  | en_IE.utf8
 en_IE.utf8 |            11 |        10 |            6 | en_IE.utf8  | en_IE.utf8
(2 rows)
```

Well, my Ubuntu does not speak German, French nor Greek but the Irish speak English and pay in euro.

```
set lc_monetary to "en_IE.utf8";
select 10::money;

 money  
--------
 €10.00
(1 row)
```

---

In Windows it is likely [that the comp speaks German:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc233982.aspx)

```
set lc_monetary to "de-DE";
```

Unfortunately, `pg_collation` does not show this.

Comment: not working for me: though I'm seeing el-GR in pg_collation, trying to set lc_monetary to "el-GR" is still giving me the ERROR invalid value for parameter "lc_monetary": "el-GR"