# Change locale from $ to ₹ in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I was developing a web application with Codeigniter 3 framework with PostgreSQL. It's an eCommerce website and the currency we used globally is Indian Rupee.

I was using data type 'money' for the field where we store the price. Now we are about to upload the application to AWS RDS & EC2 and after creating a PostgreSQL database, the currency symbol shown is $.

I am pretty new to PostgreSQL and we already migrated all our data to the server.
I would appreciate if someone will help me to change locale from $ to ₹ in PostgreSQL.

Comment: [Don't use the `money` type](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money). The problem you are having is just one of the disadvantages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set lc\_monetary for PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064945/set-lc-monetary-for-postgresql)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Is there any way I can change it permanently for PostgreSQL?